# Possible to get screen working area in Service?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen

Is it possible in a Service (i.e. not in an Activity) to get the screen's working area, i.e. its height minus the status bar height at the top and the soft key space ('back', 'home' etc) at the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

I've tried this from the service and it works for me. On 2.3 devices (tried on Galaxy Y and Nexus One) it gives the complete screen size. But on 4.x devices (tried on Nexus 4), It gives the screen size minus the status bar. If you have found a more reliable method do post.

Comment: I believe the height returned by `DisplayMetrics` excludes the soft key area **but not** the status bar. As an example, the Nexus 4's width, height is 720 x 1280. The `DisplayMetrics` returns the height, width as 720 x 1184. This discrepancy in height of 96 pixels (roughly 1/12th of the screen's overall height) is too large to be the notification bar but just right to be the soft key area. Other phones such as the HTC Desire HD and Galaxy S2 have their 'back', 'home' etc buttons outside of the screen area, hence why the height returned by `DisplayMetrics` is the screen's actual height.

Comment: Here's a reliable technique for getting the status bar height: http://mrtn.me/blog/2012/03/17/get-the-height-of-the-status-bar-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

As well as Srikant's answer, here's an alternative way of getting the display dimensions:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

This gives the same height, width as Srikant's answer.